# compaction in an array storing 2 linked lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, complexity-theory

An array Arr ( size n ) can represent doubly linked list.
  [ Say the cells have struct { int val, next, prev; } ]

I have two lists A and B stored in the array.
A has m nodes and B has n - m nodes.

These nodes being scattered, I want to rearrange them such that all nodes of A are from Arr[0] .. Arr[m-1] and rest are filled by nodes of B, in O(m) time.

The solution that occurs to me is to :

- Iterate A till a node occurs which is placed beyond Arr[m-1]
- then, iterate B till a node occurs which is placed before Arr[m]
- swap the two ( including the manipulation of the next prev links of them and their neighbours).

However in this case the total number of iterations is O(n + m). Hence there should be a better answer.

P.S:
This question occurs in [Introduction to Algorithms, 2nd edition](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?tid=8570&ttype=2).
Problem 10.3-5

Comment: I do not grok, how you come to a complexity of O(n+m). `Iterate A`  is only O(n-m) as A has only n-m elements and `iterate B` has O(m) as B has only m elements. So in sum your complexity is just O(n-m+m) = O(n). Btw. for m<n (which yields here) O(n+m) = O(2n) = O(n).

Answer (score 2):

How about iterating through list *A* and placing each element in `Arr[0] ... Arr[m-1]`, obviously swapping its position with whatever was there before and updating the prev/next links as well.  There will be a lot of swapping but nevertheless it will be *O(m)* since once you finish iterating through *A* (*m* iterations), all of its elements will be located (in order, incidentally) in the first *m* slots of `Arr`, and thus *B* must be located entirely in the rest of `Arr`.

To add some pseudocode

```
a := index of head of A 
for i in 0 ... m-1
    swap Arr[i], Arr[a]
    a := index of next element in A
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i think "jw013" is right but the idea needs some improvements :

by swapping your are changing the address of elements in the Arr array .
so you need to be careful about that !

e.g. lets say we have Arr like :

indices:     0     1     2     3     4

```
        | 2 | empty | 3 | empty | 1 |   (assume the link list is like  1 -> 2 -> 3)
```

so `Arr[4].next` is  0  and `Arr[0].next` is 2 .

but when you swap `Arr[4]` and `Arr[0]` then `Arr[0].next` is 0 .
which is not what we want to happen so we should consider adjusting pointers when swapping.

so the code for it is like :

```html
 public static void compactify(int List_head , int Free , node [] array){
        int List_lenght ;
        
        List_lenght = find_listlenght(List_head , array);
        
        if(List_lenght != 0){ // if the list is not empty
            int a = List_head;
            for (int i = 0; i < List_lenght ; i++) {

                swap( array , a , i );
                a = array[i].next;
                
                print_mem(array);
            }
        }
         
       
    }
```

now when calling swap:

```html
private static void swap(node[] array, int a, int i) {
        
        // adjust the next and prev of both array[a] and array[i]
        
        int next_a = array[a].next;
        int next_i = array[i].next;
        
        int prev_a = array[a].prev;
        int prev_i = array[i].prev;
        
        // if array[a] has a next adjust the array[next_a].prev to i
        if(next_a != -1)   
            array[next_a].prev = i;

        // if array[i] has a next adjust the array[next_i].prev to a
        if(next_i != -1)  
            array[next_i].prev = a;

        // like before adjust the pointers of array[prev_a] and array[prev_i] 

        if(prev_a != -1)
            array[prev_a].next = i;

        if(prev_i != -1)
            array[prev_i].next = a;
        
        node temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        
    }
```